# PHPUnit test a static function located in a trait

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, traits

In a piece of legacy code I was tasked to test a static function in a trait like that:

```
namespace App\Model\SomeLogic;

trait WhyDecidedToUseTrait
{
   public static function aMethodThatDoesSomeFancyStuff()
   {
     //Method Logic
   }
}
```

And from this piece of [documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.2/test-doubles.html#mocking-traits-and-abstract-classes) using the `getMockForTrait` method. But in my case making a dummy object in order to test a static function where object instants are useless to begin with has no value.

Also testing the method in objects that use this trait seems pretty much time consuming, also tdoing a larger scale refactoring is time consuming as well.

So how I can test the trait in order to gradually refactor any class that uses it?

Comment: What do you want to test on that trait? It's a single public static function, which when used creates multiple global static methods, for which I would like to learn more why you think getMockForTrait() is unfitting and/or why not use a global static method in the first place, why the trait? This should help to learn about what to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a Dummy class using this trait:

```
namespace Tests\YourTeasts;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Model\SomeLogic\WhyDecidedToUseTrait;

class Dummy
{
  use WhyDecidedToUseTrait;
}

class StoreExtraAttributesTraitTest extends TestCase
{
   public function setTheStaticMethod()
   {
      Dummy::aMethodThatDoesSomeFancyStuff();

      //Assertions are done here
   }
}
```

Hence you can test the method, but in case of coverage tests I have no idea whenther is shown or not.